# Why does my JPanel look gray with a certain size but not with another?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have a JLayeredPane with 2 JPanels inside of it.

The one on top has a semi transparant background color:

```
this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150));
```

Now when i set the size of this JPanel to be equal to the size of the frame
[image]`

```
this.ghostPanel.setSize(width, height);
```

My whole JPanel turns gray, but when i give it height - 1, It displays the correct transparant view.

[image: correct displaying view]

```
this.ghostPanel.setSize(width, height - 1);
```

I don't really understand why this happens. I would love to find a valid explanation! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please post a minimal example that highlights this phenomenon?

Comment: A picture is NOT a code example. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem. We don't know the context of how you build the panel or what the values of your width/height variables are etc... And know we don't want the whole game, just two panels, one to represent the game and the other to represent the transparent panel.

Answer (score 2):

Swing components are either opaque or transparent, Swing doesn't know how to paint components which have a alpha based color.

By using a alpha based color, Swing doesn't know that it should paint the components below it when the component is updated, so you be up with some weird paint artefacts

Instead, make the component transparent (`setOpaque(false)`), then override it's `paintComponent` method and use a `AlphaComposite` to fill the background